# Render a react ref as html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is it possible to grab a ref from a react element and render it as html? Something like:

```
    const htmlRef = useRef();

    const getHtmlFromElement = () => {
        return someSortOfFunctionToReturnHTMLStringFromElement(htmlRef.current);
    }
    return <div ref={htmlRef}>make me html!</div>
```

I have looked at using ReactDOMServer render to string however my component is burried under various contexts, templates, etc to isolate and render in that manner.

Comment: I guess you are looking for htmlRef.current.outerHTML

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @AntoninRiche ah yep that's how to do it! please reply as answer so I can give you a ✅

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for htmlRef.current.outerHTML